# ToListAsync fails on second call

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-mobile-services

I followed this [guide](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/) through Chapter 3. I have the same `AzureCloudTable` and `AzureCloudService` as the guide. I have the same `TableData` base class for the models. I'm not creating a Todo app though. Instead I have 7 models that are identical to the one I have in Azure where they use `EntityData` as the base class, just like the guide has for its Todo object.

Since I have worked through Chapter 3, I also have the sync stuff in place. In fact, my local db does get fully populated so I know the Azure part is working fine.

Where I'm struggling is that when the client in a ViewModel calls for data, it does so on the `IMobileServiceSyncTable` object with `ToListAsync()`. (Via the ViewModel's constructor just like the guide in *Chapter 1: Building the UI for the App*.)

The very first time (i.e. fist time since startup) I call `ToListAsync`, I get records, 50 or more depending on how I configured the API. The next time I call `ToListAsync`, either in a loop to get the next 50, or for another `TableData`, **I get an unhandled exception**. It doesn't matter which `TableData` object I get first or second. Any combination of the 7 throw the same exception on the second call.

No try/catch can intercede either. (As an aside, I sure would like to know why) Execution goes straight to `App.g.i.cs.InitializeComponent` where an `UnhandledException` handler exists.

The **e** object in that handler only says:

`e.Exception.Message = "Value does not fall within the expected range."`

`e.Message = "Value does not fall within the expected range."`

This mystifies me. Why does the second call fail and what does the message mean?

I'm using v2.0.0 of the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.* nuget packages in my API solution.

I'm using v4.0.2 of the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.* nuget packages in my App solution.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.6.6

Comment: Please post **here** a complete sample code. You should find the guide to create a [mcve] useful

Comment: Please post/log the full Exception, including all inner Exceptions and hte Stacktrace. The message only carries about 5% of the total information needed for Debugging. Proper Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine, and you are denying yourself and us the most basic debugging informations. Here are two articles on proper Exception handling that I link often: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: If there is a demo code to reproduce this issue, it will be helpful.